# Make Show Notes for Individual Podcast Episodes Easy to Find (multiple URL's?)

Tags: posts, pages, urls

My show notes for a podcast will be entered as a new post (like a blog post) in Wordpress (.org - hosted through bluehost, domain registration at godaddy).

The site is www.michellefit.com, but the URL specific to a page (and very long and complicated) and does not include my actual web address within it (not sure if this is an issue for what I'm trying to achieve).

Now, I want to be able to say in the podcast, "for the show notes on this episode, go to www.michellefit.com/6" (for a direct link to Episode 6 of the podcast, rather than the other two options 1) giving out the ENTIRE URL or 2) telling them to go my site, then to the Podcast tab, THEN scroll down the list of shows to find this particular one).

NEED: A step-by-step process to make this happen :-) And I am NOT a techie.

I have been researching this online for more than a month and have not yet been able to pinpoint an answer.

Thanks for reading this post, and I hope you can help! :-)

Comment: As you can read in the [help] this site is dedicated to _Developers and Administrators_. No one is unhappy to help people who just start to develop, but you'll have to show us what you tried and where you failed - see [ask] for more info.

Comment: The fact that your page links point to a different website *is* a problem that you'll need to fix.  Go to Settings, General.  What do you have in the "WordPress Address" and "Site Address" boxes?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it.  I would enter the episode number as the slug for your blog posts.

First, go to Settings, Permalinks.  Choose the "Post name" option and click the "Save Changes" button.  This does two things: It ensures that you will be able to pick a "slug" for your posts, and it prevents numbers in dates from interfering with your numeric slugs.

Next, you need to enter the slug for you blog posts.  Let's say you are creating a new blog post for episode 1, and the title of the post will be "Episode 1 Notes".  On the edit post screen, click on the Screen Options link at the top right corner of the screen.  Then make sure that the "Slug" box is checked.

Once this is checked, then just below the box where you enter the title, you will see the URL for the post you are editing.  This URL will end in something resembling your post's title, such as "episode-1-notes".  This is called the slug.  You want to change it to "1", so click on the Edit button and change the slug to "1".  When you are done editing your post, click the "Publish" button (or "Update" button if you are editing an existing post).

Now, the URL of your post is `http://example.com/1/`, and you can tell people on the podcast that they can find the notes at "example dot com slash 1".